# Grails MongoDB NoSuchFieldError: ACKNOWLEDGED

Tags: mongodb, grails

Getting error on update when using a different version mongodb java client.
I ran the dependency-report and found that only 1 jar for mongdb java driver is existing.
Please guide why this error is coming, I am trying to update domain object through GORM.

```
dependencies {
 runtime "org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:2.9.0"
}


 plugins {
compile (":mongodb:1.3.0"){
    excludes "mongo-java-driver";
}
}


Message: ACKNOWLEDGED
Line | Method
    ->>  646 | doInDB                  in                 
org.grails.datastore.mapping.mongo.engine.MongoEntityPersister$5

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    616 | updateEntry             in 
org.grails.datastore.mapping.mongo.engine.MongoEntityPersister
|     78 | updateEntry . . . . . . in     ''
|    846 | run                     in       
org.grails.datastore.mapping.engine.NativeEntryEntityPersister$2
|     33 | executePendingOperation in  
org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.impl.PendingOperationExecution
|    364 | flushPendingOperations  in org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.AbstractSession
|    343 | flushPendingUpdates . . in     ''
|    263 | flush                   in     ''
|    126 | flush . . . . . . . . . in org.grails.datastore.mapping.mongo.MongoSession
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WriteConcern.ACKNOWLEDGED is only available in the MongoDB Java Driver version 2.10 and above.  You either need to update your Mongo version:

```
dependencies {
 runtime "org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:2.10.0"
}
```

or you need to remove your exclusion of the mongo driver here:

```
compile (":mongodb:1.3.0"){
    excludes "mongo-java-driver";
}
```

and replace it with:

```
compile ":mongodb:1.3.0"
```

If you take this second option, this will use the 2.11 version of the Mongo Java Driver, which is what this plugin code is expecting.  Using a version of the driver that is older than 2.11 is likely to cause these sorts of issues.